# Django url parameter setting

Tags: django, url

I try to have open url like:

mysite.doamin/table/name1
mysite.doamin/table/name2

but without any success....

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views
from .views import Table, TableFilter

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('table/<name>', Table.as_view(), name='table'),
    path('filters_form/', TableFilter.as_view(), name='filters_form'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

template/navbar.html

```
Table
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'table' cms %}">Cms</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'table' cms %}">Sectools</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I want to set a parameter, to switch de models and show any models in the table template....

```
Reverse for 'table' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['table\\/(?P<name>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

Comment: The problem is not the path, but the `cms`, apparently there is no `cms` variable in the template.